# Parameterized skipping for Python unittests: Best practices?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have the following scenario:

- I have a list of "dangerous patterns"; each is a string that contains dangerous characters, such as `"%s with embedded ' single quote"`, `"%s with embedded \t horizontal tab"` and similar (it's about a dozen patterns).
- Each test is to be run

  - once with a vanilla pattern that does not inject dangerous characters (i.e. `"%s"`), and
  - once for each dangerous pattern.
- If the vanilla test fails, we skip the dangerous pattern tests on the assumption that they don't make much sense if the vanilla case fails.

Various other constraints:

- Stick with the batteries included in Python as far as possible (i.e. `unittest` is hopefully enough, even if `nose` would work).
- I'd like to keep the contract of `unittest.TestCase` as far as possible. I.e. the solution should not affect test discovery (which might find everything that starts with `test`, but then there's also `runTest` which may be overridden in the construction, and more variation).

I tried a few solutions, and I am not happy with any of them:

- Writing an abstract class causes `unittest` to try and run it as a test case (because it quacks like a test case). This can be worked around, but the code is getting ugly fast. Also, a whole lot of functions needs to be overridden, and for several of them the documentation is a bit unclear about what properties need to be implemented in the base class. Plus test discovery would have to be replicated, which means duplicating code from inside `unittest`.
- Writing a function that executes the tests as `SubTest`s, to be called from each test function. Requires boilerplate in every test function, and gives just a single test result for the entire series of tests.
- Write a decorator. Avoids the test case discovery problem of the abstract class approach, but has all the other problems.
- Write a decorator that takes a `TestCase` and returns a `TestSuite`. This worked best so far, but I don't know whether I can add the same `TestCase` object multiple times. Or whether `TestCase` objects can be copied or not (I have control over all of them but I don't know what the base class does or expects in this regard).

What's the best approach?

Comment: Keep it simple:  write a for loop inside the test.  Adding complexity to your test suite/runner should be discouraged (coupled tests, for example, prevent you from running testing in parallel).

Comment: The tests are inherently coupled.  
If the base case fails, the dangerous-character variants will most likely fail for the same reason. This means the signal will be amplified with noise by a factor of 12, and believe me, having to scroll up beyond that noise is making testing a real pain.  
So this is indeed a legit case for coupled tests.  
  
Fair point though: Does a `TestSuite` run its tests in parallel? If yes, then the `TestSuite` approach will fail.